# CSS Animation Directional Issue

Tags: css, css-animations

We are trying to animate a div as follows:

1- Stretch from 0 to 100% (from left to right)

2- Then shrink from 100% to 0 (also from left to right)

3- then repeat.

We have the following div:

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  background: #c60000;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  color: #789;
  width: 0;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-name: progress;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
    
@keyframes progress {
  50% {
    // transform-origin: right top;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

But no matter what we do using transform-origin and floats, positioning etc, the second part shrinks from right to left. i.e. the left side is always the anchor, whereas we want the right side to be the anchor when shrinking is taking place.

Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  background: #c60000;
  top: 0;
  color: #789;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-name: progress;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}
    
@keyframes progress {
  0% {
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
  }
  50% {
    right: 0;    
    width: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    right: 0;      
    width: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```